# Consumer saga vs Automatonymous in MassTransit

Tags: masstransit, automatonymous

What exactly is a consumer saga, and how is it different from Automatonymous? I know that Automatonymous is a separate library that is used by MassTransit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consumer sagas, for lack of a better name, are the original sagas implemented by MassTransit when it was created 13 years ago. They were *consumers with state* and used variants of `IConsumer<T>` to direct messages to saga instances. [Consumer sagas](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/consumer-saga.html) implement one or more interfaces to consume correlated saga events. This support is included so that it is easy to move applications from other saga implementations to MassTransit.

[State Machine Sagas](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/automatonymous.html), which use Automatonymous, provide a powerful state machine syntax to create sagas. They are more flexible in terms of event correlation, and have a fluent syntax for defining state and behavior. They also work nicely with dependency injection via the creation of custom activities which are resolved at run-time for each message.

> Automatonymous was written separately to enable its use out of MassTransit, but it by the same author (me).

Comment: Where exactly does a consumer saga define and preserve its state?

Comment: Properties on the consumer saga class are persisted, so that's where the _state_ is preserved.